# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "excon" for gem mandrill-api

Tags: bundler, fog, mandrill, excon

I'm getting this error when trying to install bundle. I have both versions '0.15.4' and '0.25.1' of gem excon in my gemset. How can I fix this?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "excon":
```

In Gemfile:
    mandrill-api (>= 0) ruby depends on
      excon (~> 0.15.4) ruby

```
fog (~> 1.10.1) ruby depends on
  excon (0.25.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my Gemfile.lock, if that doesn't work try running `gem update excon` and check that you have the version installed with `gem list | grep excon` for the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of this, I suspect you have likely found an answer. That said, I think if you update fog you should have better luck. Sorry for the difficulty.